# CSS layout: fixed-fluid-fixed, maintain 200px grid

Tags: css, responsive-design, fluid-layout

This is my first question on Stack Overflow, so I hope I'm following all of the proper etiquette! I'm trying to create a layout that is fixed-fluid-fixed, where the two sidebars are always 200px and the center content area is variable based on the side of the screen. I have gotten this to work with the following code.

```
#page-container {
    margin: 15px;
}

#content-container {
    margin: 0 200px;
}

#left-sidebar{
    width: 185px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

#right-sidebar{
    float:right;
    width: 185px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

I am using an Isotope Masonry layout (that works in columns of 200px) in the center - which is why I want the center area to be fluid. Here comes the question: what I would like would be for the center area to be fluid but restricted to multiples of 200px. So, on a 1024 screen - the sidebars would be 200px, and the center would be 600, leaving margins of 12px. Or on a retina display of 2880, the sidebars would still be 200px and the center would be 2400px, leaving margins of 40px. Is this possible? I'm working on the site right now, so it may change throughout the day but the layout should remain constant: http://test.loeuf.com/wp/

Comment: You can adapt this layout method for your purpose http://isotope.metafizzy.co/custom-layout-modes/centered-masonry.html and then use media queries in order to serve the right #container width depending on the detected viewing device.

Comment: Thanks! I had seen the centered masonry option, but somehow didn't make the connection.